# Find minimum value in a map java

Tags: java, data-structures

I need to find min values  in a map. How i can do? I can't use any data structure and i have to make in O(n) time.
This code not work..but can be a a starting point
I can't use java 8.

```
 Entry<K, V> min=null;
    for (Entry<K, V> entry : M.entries()) {
        min=entry;
        if(c.compare(min.getValue(),entry.getValue())>0){
            min=entry;
        }
        System.out.println("MIN "+min);
    }
```

Comment: Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple java8 solution for map `Map<Object,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();`

```
map.values().stream().min(Integer::compare).get();
```

**Edit**
As @Andreas pointed out, there was request for using comparator, so this is solution for Java 8 which finds smallest value

```
public static <K, V> V min8(Map<K, V> map, Comparator<V> comp) {
    return map.values().stream().min(comp).get();
}
```

and this is solution for Java 7 for finding entry with smallest value

```
public static <K, V> Entry<K, V> min(Map<K, V> map, Comparator<V> comp) {
        Iterator<Entry<K, V>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
        if (!entries.hasNext()) {
            return null;
        }
        Entry<K, V> min;
        for (min = entries.next(); entries.hasNext();) {
            Entry<K, V> value = entries.next();
            if (comp.compare(value.getValue(), min.getValue()) < 0) {
                min = value;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
```

my initial solution was very close to @Andreas, so i decide to change and use for loop with itterator.

Comment: I can't use java 8

Comment: @FilomenaDelSorbo That would have been a relevant piece of information in the question, don't you think?

Comment: Both options are assuming that value is an `Integer`. The fact that question uses a `Comparator` (variable `c`) would indicate otherwise. Also, question seems to seek the minimum `Entry` (key + value), not just the minimum value.

Comment: @Andreas good point, fixed for java 7, and too lazy to fix it for java 8. which i think is not relevant as op does not use java 8

Answer (score 0):

If you always set `min = entry` in the beginning of the loop, you're always comparing the entry to itself. Remove that line, then also guard against the initial null value of `min`, and you get:

```
Entry<K, V> min = null;
for (Entry<K, V> entry : M.entries()) {
    if (min == null || c.compare(min.getValue(), entry.getValue()) > 0) {
        min = entry;
    }
}
```

If you only need the value, not the key too, then use the `values()` call to iterate:

```
V min = null;
for (V value : M.values()) {
    if (min == null || c.compare(min, value) > 0) {
        min = entry;
    }
}
```

Of course, in both cases it is *assumed* that no value in the Map will be null. A null value would cause `NullPointerException`, unless the `Comparator` can handle them.